# How to unnest two lists from two columns in BigQuery without cross product, as individual rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery, it has two columns, each column contains an array. for a given row, both columns will contain arrays of the same length, but that length can vary from row to row:

```
WITH tbl AS (
select ['a','b','c'] AS one, [1,2,3] as two
union all
select ['a','x'] AS two, [10,20] as two
)
select * from tbl
```

So the table will look like:

```
row | one     | two
-----------------------
1   | [a,b,c] | [1,2,3]
2   | [a,x]   | [10,20]
```

I would like to unnest in such a way that each row, in the new table, will have an element of an array from column1 and an corresponding element from column2. So from the table above, I am looking to get:

```
row | one | two
---------
1   | a   | 1
2   | b   | 2
3   | c   | 3
4   | a   | 10
5   | x   | 20
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT z.*
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT one, two
  FROM UNNEST(one) one WITH OFFSET
  JOIN UNNEST(two) two WITH OFFSET
  USING(OFFSET)
  )
) z
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question - result will be

```
Row one two  
1   a   1    
2   b   2    
3   c   3    
4   a   10   
5   x   20
```

> I dont fully understand the syntax, could you please explain it?

Explanation:

- Step 1

for each row in table below array is calculated

```
ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT one, two
  FROM UNNEST(one) one WITH OFFSET
  JOIN UNNEST(two) two WITH OFFSET
  USING(OFFSET)
)
```

Elements of this array are structs with respective value from two column - they are being matched with each other by JOIN'ing on their positions in initial arrays (OFFSET)

- Step 2

Then this array gets UNNEST'ed and cross JOIN'ed with respective row in the table - and whole row is actually ignored and only that struct (`z`) is being brought into to the output

- Step 3

And finally to output not a a struct but rather as a separate columns -  `z.*` is used

Hope this helped :o)

Comment: Thank you Mikhail, works great. But I dont fully understand the syntax, could you please explain it? thanks!