# is there a way to unnest bigquery array independently?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say I have this database:

```
with tbl as (
select 
  ['Unknown','Eletric','High Voltage'] AS product_category, 
  ['Premium','New'] as client_cluster
) select * from tbl
```

And its output:

```
row | product_category                  | client_cluster
--------------------------------------------------------------
1   | [Unknown, Eletric, High Voltage]  | [Premium, New]
```

I would like to unnest this columns independently in a way that it will be then N rows where N would be the size of the biggest array I unnest and the output would look like this:

```
row | product_category     | client_cluster
---------------------------------------------
1   | Unknown              | Premium
2   | Eletric              | New
3   | High Voltage         | Null
```

And there is no order that I would like to imply. Is there a way to do that? I tried [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59959165/how-to-unnest-two-lists-from-two-columns-in-bigquery-without-cross-product-as-i) but in my case it did not work as expected because of my arrays does not have the same size.

Comment: array length of `product_category` can be less than that of `client_cluster`? If not, use *left join* instead of *inner* or *comma* join.

Comment: there is no rule I know to guarantee that so the solution should expect every scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it did not work as expected because of my arrays does not have the same size.

for your specific sample in your question, you can `left join` unnested arrays.

```sql
WITH tbl AS (
  SELECT ['Unknown','Eletric','High Voltage'] AS product_category, ['Premium','New'] as client_cluster 
)
SELECT p AS product_category, c AS client_cluster 
  FROM tbl, UNNEST(product_category) p WITH offset
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(client_cluster) c WITH offset USING (offset);
```

[image]

But the length of `product_category` is less than that of `client_cluster`, it won't work as you wish.

```sql
WITH tbl AS (
  SELECT ['Eletric','High Voltage'] AS product_category, ['Supreme', 'Premium','New'] as client_cluster 
)
SELECT p AS product_category, c AS client_cluster 
  FROM tbl, UNNEST(product_category) p WITH offset
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(client_cluster) c WITH offset USING (offset);
```

[image]

I might be wrong, but as far as I know you can't use `FULL JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` with flattened array to solve this issue. If you try to do so, you will get:

> Query error: Array scan is not allowed with FULL JOIN: UNNEST expression at [31:13]

So you might consider below workaround using a *hidden table(array)* for join key.

```sql
WITH tbl AS (
  SELECT 1 id, ['Unknown','Eletric','High Voltage'] AS product_category, ['Premium','New'] as client_cluster,
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id, ['Eletric','High Voltage'], ['Premium','New', 'Supreme']
)
SELECT id, p AS product_category, c AS client_cluster 
  FROM tbl, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, GREATEST(ARRAY_LENGTH(client_cluster), ARRAY_LENGTH(product_category)) - 1)) o0
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(product_category) p WITH offset o1 ON o0 = o1
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(client_cluster) c WITH offset o2 ON o0 = o2;
```

**Query results**

[image]